# Spark RDD - Replacing the missing columns with the average of other columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD like below

```
RDD( (001, 1, 0, 3, 4), (001, 3, 4, 1, 7), (001, , 0, 6, 4), (003, 1, 4, 5, 7), (003, 5, 4, , 2), (003, 4, , 9, 2), (003, 2, 3, 0, 1) )
```

the first column is the contract id(001 and 003), I need to group the records with similar contract ids and find the average of all the columns other than the contract id and substitute the missing columns with the average of those columns related to that contract id.

So, the final output would be

```
RDD( (001, 1, 0, 3, 4), (001, 3, 4, 1, 7), (001, (1+3)/3 , 0, 6, 4), (003, 1, 4, 5, 7), (003, 5, 4, (5+9+0)/4 , 2), (003, 4, (4+4+3)/4 , 9, 2), (003, 2, 3, 0, 1) )
```

I did the groupByKey using contract id as the key and I got stuck after that. I really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Create the exact input data provided as a Spark DataFrame/DataSet
val df = {
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val simpleSchema = StructType(
    StructField("a", StringType) ::
    StructField("b", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("c", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("d", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("e", IntegerType) :: Nil)

  val data = List(
    Row("001", 1, 0, 3, 4),
    Row("001", 3, 4, 1, 7),
    Row("001", null, 0, 6, 4),
    Row("003", 1, 4, 5, 7),
    Row("003", 5, 4, null, 2),
    Row("003", 4, null, 9, 2),
    Row("003", 2, 3, 0, 1)
  )

  spark.createDataFrame(data.asJava, simpleSchema)
}

// fill replaces nulls with zero, which we need for the desired averaging.    
val avgs = df.na.fill(0).groupBy(col("a")).avg("b", "c", "d", "e").as("avgs")

val output = df.as("df").join(avgs, col("df.a") === col("avgs.a")).select(col("df.a"),
  coalesce(col("df.b"), col("avg(b)")),
  coalesce(col("df.c"), col("avg(c)")),
  coalesce(col("df.d"), col("avg(d)")),
  coalesce(col("df.e"), col("avg(e)"))
  )

scala> df.show()
+---+----+----+----+---+
|  a|   b|   c|   d|  e|
+---+----+----+----+---+
|001|   1|   0|   3|  4|
|001|   3|   4|   1|  7|
|001|null|   0|   6|  4|
|003|   1|   4|   5|  7|
|003|   5|   4|null|  2|
|003|   4|null|   9|  2|
|003|   2|   3|   0|  1|
+---+----+----+----+---+


scala> avgs.show()
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+------+
|  a|            avg(b)|            avg(c)|            avg(d)|avg(e)|
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+------+
|003|               3.0|              2.75|               3.5|   3.0|
|001|1.3333333333333333|1.3333333333333333|3.3333333333333335|   5.0|
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+------+


scala> output.show()
+---+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|  a|coalesce(df.b, avg(b))|coalesce(df.c, avg(c))|coalesce(df.d, avg(d))|coalesce(df.e, avg(e))|
+---+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|001|                   1.0|                   0.0|                   3.0|                   4.0|
|001|                   3.0|                   4.0|                   1.0|                   7.0|
|001|    1.3333333333333333|                   0.0|                   6.0|                   4.0|
|003|                   1.0|                   4.0|                   5.0|                   7.0|
|003|                   5.0|                   4.0|                   3.5|                   2.0|
|003|                   4.0|                  2.75|                   9.0|                   2.0|
|003|                   2.0|                   3.0|                   0.0|                   1.0|
+---+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the above example I have only 5 columns, what if I had to average more than 50 columns?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using the Window functions in sql without using any joins. Check this out:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("001", Some(1), Some(0), Some(3), Some(4)),
  ("001", Some(3), Some(4), Some(1), Some(7)),
  ("001", None, Some(0), Some(6), Some(4)),
  ("003", Some(1), Some(4), Some(5), Some(7)),
  ("003", Some(5), Some(4), None, Some(2)),
  ("003", Some(4), None, Some(9), Some(2)),
  ("003", Some(2), Some(3), Some(0), Some(1))
).toDF("a","b","c","d","e")
df.show(false)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("avg_temp")

spark.sql("""  select a, coalesce(b,sum(b) over(partition by a)/count(*) over(partition by a)) b1, coalesce( c, sum(c) over(partition by a)/count(*) over(partition by a)) c1,
            coalesce( d, sum(d) over(partition by a)/count(*) over(partition by a)) d1, coalesce( e, sum(e) over(partition by a)/count(*) over(partition by a)) e1 from avg_temp
""").show(false)
```

Results:

```
+---+----+----+----+---+
|a  |b   |c   |d   |e  |
+---+----+----+----+---+
|001|1   |0   |3   |4  |
|001|3   |4   |1   |7  |
|001|null|0   |6   |4  |
|003|1   |4   |5   |7  |
|003|5   |4   |null|2  |
|003|4   |null|9   |2  |
|003|2   |3   |0   |1  |
+---+----+----+----+---+
+---+------------------+----+---+---+
|a  |b1                |c1  |d1 |e1 |
+---+------------------+----+---+---+
|003|1.0               |4.0 |5.0|7.0|
|003|5.0               |4.0 |3.5|2.0|
|003|4.0               |2.75|9.0|2.0|
|003|2.0               |3.0 |0.0|1.0|
|001|1.0               |0.0 |3.0|4.0|
|001|3.0               |4.0 |1.0|7.0|
|001|1.3333333333333333|0.0 |6.0|4.0|
+---+------------------+----+---+---+
```